# Search for node inside circle (SKShapeNode) with lowest y-coordinate

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I want to search for nodes inside a circle - the circle is a SKShapeNode. The return node (SKSpriteNode) should be the nodes found inside the circle, with the lowest y-value.

For people who are interested, this is the code I use for the search:

```
SKSpriteNode *currentNode =  [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] size:CGSizeMake(0, 0)];
[currentNode setPosition:CGPointMake(0, 99999)];

SKShapeNode *circle = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:100];

// adding circle and other nodes to scene    

[self enumerateChildNodesWithName://* usingBlock:^(SKSpriteNode *foundNode, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
if ([circle containsPoint:currentNode.position]) {
    if (currentNode.position.y > foundNode.position.y) {
       currentNode = foundNode;
    }
}];

// currentNode = node inside circle with lowest y
```

I don't like this solution, looks like it takes too much effort to find just the one node. I also tried using nodesAtPoint/nodeAtPoint but that does not work in my project - 'big' child nodes.

I am curious: is there an easier way to search for a node with specifics like this?

Comment: im afraid not. I think That is the only way to check for the nodes.

Comment: "I also tried using nodesAtPoint/nodeAtPoint but that does not work in my project". I don't get that, why would it not work? Are you sure you're not just using it improperly? You should be able to work up from the lowest point in the circle and keep calling nodeAtPoint until you get a node returned and that would be the lowest node. With a small amount of nodes, it'll be a similar speed to your current method. With a large amount, it will be significantly faster.

Comment: It doesn't work because it the nodes have (big) children, I only want to detect the 'main' node. I can't find it again but I thought nodesatpoint automatically searches for the children of the node. If this is not true, please tell me, but I assume it is.          Also: why would it be faster that way? If the circle is big (and the nodes relatively small), you have a lot of points to check in the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the Y coordinate is going to be much faster than [circle containsPoint] so you might want to change the order of your condition to first compare the y coordinate of candidate nodes and only check circle containsPoint for nodes that have a y coordinate between the lowest point of your circle (-100) and the currentNode's Y coordinate.

something like :

```
if ( foundNode.position.y > -100 
     && foundNode.position.y < currentNode.position.y )
{
  if ([circle containsPoint:foundNode.position])
  { currentNode = foundNode }
}
```

note: i'm assuming enemy.position was actually meant to be foundNode.position.

Comment: Yes, that is a good addition, thanks. I was also thinking about using an array with the nodes (only the nodes that should be checked) and searching those nodes instead of all nodes with enumerateChildNodesWithName://* . I am still wondering though, if there is an easier way to do all of this.

Comment: Did you look into SKPhysicsContact ? perhaps it could be used in your context

Comment: It does work in my context, filling the array each time a node enters the circle and removing the node when it ends contact with the circle. Thanks for the idea!